# Is it possible to automatically export a calendar appointments into an email via powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, office365, outlook-2016

Let me give a breif explanation of what my current work process, then after how I want to automate this.

I work on the change team for my company and use outlook to note the changes. Our build window is every Friday and at the end of the week Friday will be covered in changes. For each calendar event we fill out the subject line, location and the body. The subject line will contain ticket number, Developer name and app name. The location line will containt either "Staged" or "Complete", if the change is not complete we do not send in the email. Within the body we contain the direct wesbite link for that specific ticket. At the end of the day I send an email of all of the "Completed" changes where I copy/paste the subject line in the email, I then copy/paste the hyperlink from the body to teh ticket numbet in the subject line.

Without purchasing another tool thanks to cost cuts we are looking to automate this with powershell. We want powershell to be able to take the subject line and drop it into an email, and then take the hypelink and attached it to the ticket number in the subject line pasted over. I have no experience wtih powershell so learning this from scratch. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so where to start?

Comment: Im going to assume you're a windows admin so you should understand ports, protocols, and basic computer terminology. Unfortunately, we are not a code writing service but, you're asking if its possible, which it is. You will have to come up with the code yourself and we can help troubleshoot the code youre struggling with; we wont write it for you. Take a look at the following link: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/send-email-windows-powershell/#:~:text=How%20to%20Send%20an%20Email%20Using%20PowerShell%201,the%20email%20sense%20securely.%20...%20More%20items...

Comment: Thanks for the help, @AbrahamZinala! Correct the main query was if it was possible. Now I know I can fully invest my time into this. That link helps a lot with part of this process.

Comment: Yes --- MSOffice apps automation is a very common thing: ['PowerShell outlook automation'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+outlook+automation%27&t=h_&ia=web) --- [Youtube - PowerShell Outlook](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+outlook)